# Making arrow head without using image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a right arrow head alone with a title without using an image. But I can not figure it out. Hope someone will help me out.

HTML :

```
<h4>This is for My Title</h4>
```

CSS :

```
h4 {
  color: #666;
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

h4:after { 
  content:" ";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid green;
  margin: 0 10px;

}
```

This is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHShC/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:after` has a display of `inline`, so it's ignoring the `height`. Set the `display` to `inline-block`.

```css
h4:after {
    display: inline-block;
    /* ... */
}
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/FHShC/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

A good and more simpler way to achieve this would be to use the following HTML/CSS.

I have added an element into the `H4` to be the placeholder for the arrowhead.

### HTML

```
<h4>This is for My Title <span class="arrow-right"></span></h4>
```

### CSS

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/FHShC/2/

CSS courtesy: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 1):

Use a suitable *character* like “▶” BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE (U+25B6), e.g. with

```
h4:after { 
  content:" \25b6";
}
```

Using an image is generally more reliable, though, since there are potential font issues with special characters. An image also lets you select the exact shape you want.